# My HTML isn't linking to my CSS in

Tags: html, css

I have some simple html and css code. Each file is in the same folder, so it is not a path error. I can't figure out what's going wrong when trying to link the css. When I run the code, the html runs fine, just without any formatting.

Here's my html:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Libby Taylor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheets" type="text/css" href="libby_css.css">
</head>
<body>  
  <h1>Libby Taylor</h1>
  <div>
    <ul class = 'tabs'>
      <li>Research</li>
      <lI>Writing</li>
      <li>Home</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>


</html>
```

And here's my css:

```
body{
    color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `rel="stylesheets"`, but it should be `rel="stylesheet"`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libby_css.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in rel="stylesheets" it should be stylesheet (without s)

The full link would be `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libby_css.css">`

Answer (score 0):

The correct rel value is 'stylesheet', not 'stylesheets', try this, please.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libby_css.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libby_css.css" />`

Not stylesheets, stylesheet. Also make sure that you are using correct HTML syntax, because `class = ' tabs '` is pretty weird. It might not cause errors now, but using conventionally correct notation is always a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small typo. Should be `rel="stylesheet"` not `rel="stylesheets"`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libby_css.css">
```